# Length of pySpark is bigger than when using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am experimenting with different ways to load data into dataframes.
One of the frameworks I am looking into is PySpark, but when I load a CSV with 14149 Rows and return the length of the df, it returns 14153, while pandas return 14149.

```
  #pandas 
  df = pd.read_csv("data_file.csv")
  print df.shape

  #spark
  spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Task_1") \
    .getOrCreate()
  df = spark.read.csv("data_file.csv")
  print(df.toPandas().shape)
```

The result is (14149, 5), (14153, 5)

When I am inspecting the spark df, the head looks fine, and also the tail has the correct information, but the id number is off. Where are the extra four rows coming from, and how can I prevent pySpark from adding rows to a df, that are not in the src file?

Link to the file:
[training.csv](https://anonymfile.com/OEgRK/training.csv)

Comment: What is `data`? A buffer, a filename?

Comment: It is a file path to the csv file, I edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Can you try `df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load('data_file.csv')`? Can you share your file?

Comment: and try `df = pd.read_csv("data_file.csv", skip_blank_lines=False)`

Comment: @Corralien yes df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load('data_file.csv') works. Do you, by any chance, know why the previous approach add lines? While yours don't?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I always use this code to read a csv file with some options like 'header' and 'inferSchema'. I can probably give you more information with the file.

Comment: I added the file to the Question. It is just a random dataset I found online so I can experiment with pySpark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 bad lines in your file where the separator is not `','` but `\t` (lines 12657, 12658, 12659):

```
nt-12657    which location has the east-west game been played at the least? csv/203-csv/636.csv Oakland, CA|San Antonio, TX
nt-12658    the most matches were in what year? csv/204-csv/962.csv 2011-12
nt-12659    what was the last single released?  csv/203-csv/696.csv Je me souviens de tout"""
```

Pandas drops this rows while PySpark loads it (3 rows). Pandas considers the first row as header while PySpark don't (1 row). The difference is indeed 4 lines.

You can use:

```
# df = pd.read_csv('training.csv', index_col=0)
df = spark.read.csv('training.csv', header=True).toPandas().dropna().set_index('_c0')
print(df.shape)

# Output
(14149, 5)
```